# Transform dataframe in to presence absence by year (including missing years)

Tags: r

I am sure this is something that is quite simple I just can't seem to find a way. I wish to convert a dataframe which lists ID number, the year of the first contact and each subsequent contact year. I wish to convert this in to presence per year for each unique ID (to facilitate survival analysis), but also include the missing years from the dataset (this is where other answers to similar questions do not seem to help me). Do I just need to add the missing years manually and then use some sort of Match function? Many thanks in advance.

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I have a data frame of contact years and starting years that I wish to convert in to a presence/absence data frame

```
dat0<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),Contact_yr=c(1990,1991,1992,1994,1996,1997,2000,1998,1999,2001,2003,2006,2007,2008,2010,2012,2014),Start_yr=c(1989,1989,1989,1993,1993,1993,1993,1997,1997,2000,2000,2000,2000,2000,2009,2009,2009))
```

I started by working out the start year and the final year for each ID

```
dat1<-dat0 %>%
group_by(ID) %>%
mutate(first = first(Start_yr),
last = last(Contact_yr))%>% 
distinct(ID, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
select(ID,first,last)
```

I tried to use spread to get the data frame but this is not quite right

```
dat1 %>% 
spread(first,last)
```

This is the structure I am after:

```
what_I_want<-data.frame(ID=c(1,2,3,4,5),
                        "1989"=c(1,0,0,0,0),
                        "1990"=c(1,0,0,0,0),    
                        "1991"=c(1,0,0,0,0),    
                        "1992"=c(1,0,0,0,0),    
                        "1993"=c(0,1,0,0,0),    
                        "1994"=c(0,1,0,0,0),    
                        "1995"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "1996"=c(0,1,0,0,0),    
                        "1997"=c(0,1,1,0,0),    
                        "1998"=c(0,0,1,0,0),    
                        "1999"=c(0,0,1,0,0),    
                        "2000"=c(0,0,1,1,0),    
                        "2001"=c(0,0,0,1,0),    
                        "2002"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "2003"=c(0,0,0,1,0),    
                        "2004"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "2005"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "2006"=c(0,0,0,1,0),    
                        "2007"=c(0,0,0,1,0),    
                        "2008"=c(0,0,0,1,0),    
                        "2009"=c(0,0,0,0,1),    
                        "2010"=c(0,0,0,0,1),    
                        "2011"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "2012"=c(0,0,0,0,1),    
                        "2013"=c(0,0,0,0,0),    
                        "2014"=c(0,0,0,0,1))
```

Comment: You should have a look at `package(igraph)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One `tidyverse` possibility could be:

```
dat0 %>%
 gather(var, val, -ID) %>%
 group_by(ID) %>%
 distinct(val, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
 ungroup() %>%
 mutate(var = 1) %>%
 complete(ID, nesting(val = full_seq(val, 1))) %>%
 spread(val, var, fill = 0)

     ID `1989` `1990` `1991` `1992` `1993` `1994` `1995` `1996` `1997` `1998`
  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1    1.     1.     1.     1.     1.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
2    2.     0.     0.     0.     0.     1.     1.     0.     1.     1.     0.
3    3.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     1.     1.
4    4.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
5    5.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.     0.
# ... with 16 more variables: `1999` <dbl>, `2000` <dbl>, `2001` <dbl>,
#   `2002` <dbl>, `2003` <dbl>, `2004` <dbl>, `2005` <dbl>, `2006` <dbl>,
#   `2007` <dbl>, `2008` <dbl>, `2009` <dbl>, `2010` <dbl>, `2011` <dbl>,
#   `2012` <dbl>, `2013` <dbl>, `2014` <dbl>
```

Here it, first, transforms the data from wide to long format. Second, it keeps only the distinct years per ID. Third, for every ID, it adds all years between minimum and maximum year in the data. Finally, it transforms the data to wide format.